# Как переместиться на следующую строку в bitrix CDBResult

Tags: битрикс, php

Добрый день, есть объект класса `CDBResult`. Делаю

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM markets WHERE id IN (17,11,9,8);';    
if($res = $DB->Query($sql)){
тут надо как-то циклом перебрать элементы
}
```

Как перебрать элементы?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для работы с CDBResult можно использовать метод Fetch.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM markets WHERE id IN (17,11,9,8);';
if ($res = $DB->Query($sql)) {
  while($arRes = $res->Fetch()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cdbresult/fetch.php